# Remplazar switch con polimorfismo

Tags: java, android, refactoring

Estoy trabajando en android con room y tengo las siguientes querys dao

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE data > 0 ORDER BY name")
 List<User> usersOrderByName();

@Query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE data > 0 ORDER BY ASC")
 List<User> usersOrderByASC();

@Query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE data > 0 ORDER BY DESC")
 List<User> usersOrderByDESC();
```

Tengo un sharedPreferences que guarda un int

```
preferences.getOrder()
```

Y este es mi switch que quiero refactorizar ya que se meteran mas querys y aumentaran los case

```
switch (preferences.getOrder()) {
                    case 0:
                        return userDao.usersOrderByName();

                    case 1:
                        return userDao.usersOrderByASC();

                    case 2:
                        return userDao.usersOrderByDESC();

}
```

al final tengo ese codigo metido en un asynctask

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<User>>() {

            @Override
            protected List<User> doInBackground(Void... voids) {

                switch (preferences.getOrder()) {
                    case 0:
                        return userDao.usersOrderByName();

                    case 1:
                        return userDao.usersOrderByASC();

                    case 2:
                        return userDao.usersOrderByDESC();

                }

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(List<User> users) {
                if(users!=null){
                   presenter.returnUserList(users);
                }
            }

        }.execute();
```

Como podria eliminar ese swicth

Answer (score 0):

Puedes convertir las tres consultas en una sola usando expresiones case para indicar el tipo de orden:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE data > 0 ORDER BY CASE WHEN :orden = 1 THEN nombre END 
     , CASE WHEN :orden = 2 THEN ASC END , CASE WHEN :orden = 3 THEN DESC END")
     List<User> usersOrdered(int orden);
```

Y para llamarla:

```
int orden = preferences.getOrder();

return usersOrdered(orden);
```